# How to upload TXT files to Google AutoML Natural Language?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to upload some files to annotate and train inside AutoMl to extract entities. But I have been receiving errors in the process. For example When I used PDF files, and create the JSONL files with their corresponding CSV file I hadn't problems, but after that I applied OCR in some scanned documents, I followed the guide and I used this script:

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/scripts/input_helper_v2.py?_gac=1.88279529.1589302044.CjwKCAjwkun1BRAIEiwA2mJRWeRJRDpqVkcxBu3um5PTXjp1KaVgPITbHqK9OunNca4lrI_MlZfVthoC748QAvD_BwE&_ga=2.177424421.-1405970329.1585427512

I installed python 2.7 in new anaconda environment, finally when I try to use this script, it is not working for me.

Uploading 57 files (including csv and local PDF files) to gs://mybucket ...
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\envs\jsonl\Scripts\gsutil-script.py", line 5, in 
    from gslib.__main__ import main
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\envs\jsonl\lib\site-packages\gslib__main__.py", line 66, in 
    import httplib2
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\envs\jsonl\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line 482
    print("%s:" % h, end=" ", file=self._fp)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input_helper_v2.py", line 686, in 
    main()
  File "input_helper_v2.py", line 678, in main
    UploadFiles(annotated_files, FLAGS.target_gcs_directory)
  File "input_helper_v2.py", line 651, in UploadFiles
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\envs\jsonl\lib\subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'gsutil -m cp*** c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\analisis_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_kredit_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_av_villas_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\cifin_parte_4.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_6.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\fiduprevisora_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\entrevista_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\data_credito_mini_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_kredit_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_colpatria_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_5.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\fopep_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_ck_tr_parte_4.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\apc_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_7.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_ck_tr_parte_5.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\data_credito_mini_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\terminacion_proceso_embargo_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_10.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\cifin_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\apc_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\entrevista_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_av_villas_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\fomaq_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\data_credito_mini_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\cifin_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_av_villas_parte_4.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\entrevista_parte_4.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_ck_tr_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_colpatria_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_kredit_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_gnb_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_9.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\soporte_pago_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\entrevista_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_gnb_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_av_villas_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\colpensiones_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\cedulas_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_ck_tr_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\paz_y_salvo_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\levantamiento_embargo_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_parte_3.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_8.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\secretaria_popayan_parte_4.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\ape_parte1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\c_ck_tr_parte_1.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\analisis_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\cifin_parte_2.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\cifin_parte_5.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\data_credito_mini_parte_4.jsonl c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\dataset.csv gs://mybucket' returned non-zero exit status 1

If someone could help, I'll be grateful...

Comment: A non-zero exit code means that the process exited with some kind of error. Can you post the error here?

Comment: Look the bold text in the original post.

Comment: Do you have anything wrong with `c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\temp\tmprxwqnj\dataset.csv gs://mybucket`?